# error using neo4j in jdk tools

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

i was trying to run example from neo4j but was unable to so i think there's an error of packages not found can anyone please solve yhis 4 me. thanks in advance

```
D:\Practice>javac EmbeddedNeo4j.java>a.txt
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:4: package org.neo4j.graphdb does not exist
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
                        ^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:5: package org.neo4j.graphdb does not exist
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
                        ^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:6: package org.neo4j.graphdb does not exist
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
                        ^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:7: package org.neo4j.graphdb does not exist
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
                        ^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:8: package org.neo4j.graphdb does not exist
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
                        ^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:9: package org.neo4j.graphdb does not exist
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
                        ^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:10: package org.neo4j.graphdb.factory does not exist
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
                                ^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:11: package org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util does not exist
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils;
                                 ^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:12: package org.neo4j.kernel does not exist
import  org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker;
                        ^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GraphDatabaseService
location: class EmbeddedNeo4j
GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Node
location: class EmbeddedNeo4j
Node firstNode;
^
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:24: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Node


    20 errors;
```

help me removing these errors so that i could run my code and i coulb be able to use neo4j as my backend

Comment: You first need to learn about Java basics like packages and classpaths.

Comment: sir my java programs are running effectively and i am using sql as my backend too but i am not able to use neo4j in my java program. i might  have missed something while connecting them. can you help me out in this.

Comment: Running effectively how? I don't expect you're manually calling `javac` if you have other things working.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have `neo4j-kernel-<version>.jar` on your classpath (together with its transitive dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already figured it out but just in case, download the jar files from one of the links provided in this page http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html and copy these jar files to the Java\jdk(version)\jre\lib\ext folder.